# How does MW2 hide connection information from netstat?

Tags: network-programming

Today I was playing Modern Warfare 2.  I was hosting ground war.  There were something like 20 people playing. A notoroius blatant hacker joined.   I wanted to get rid of him.  My idea was to start adding ports to my firewall to find him and block him out.

When I opened up netstat this is what I found.
[alt text http://www.phantix-llc.com/netstat_data.jpg](http://www.phantix-llc.com/netstat_data.jpg)

The last entry is immediately after I quit the game.  The last IP shown belongs to steam.

How does MW2 hide all the incoming connections from netstat?

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be using UDP not TCP, so won't have fixed connections. Unfortunately you're not going to be able to find his IP from netstat for UDP; you'll have to look it up in-game.

To get more useful information from netstat, you wanted `netstat -ano`: that'll also show your open UDP listen sockets and the program IDs that own each one. You can then use task manager (view, select columns, add PID column) to identify which ones are owned by MW2. But UDP doesn't have fixed connections so it won't show information about who externally is using your UDP connections.

Comment: I have to be able to push information out to the players as a server.  How can I find that IP info?

Comment: The MW2 server code will know it. There must be a way to query MW2 - an admin console or something? At a pinch you can install an ethernet logger such as Ethereal and watch the packets generated by the game, but I'd be very surprised if there wasn't an admin / ban interface inside the game. (But I've never played it.)

Comment: There is no admin/Ban interface.  There are no interfaces at all.  Infinitywar/valve made it so there is NO control by players.  There are no admins.  It sucks.

Comment: Ethereal looks promising.  There is a lot of data collected and there appears to be an API.
There must also be some kind of .NET framework to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are admin tools for mwf2,allso writing status in the console "pressing ctrl+alt+supr in game so u can see console behind". Also `aIWNet_crt_u.exe` "cheat reporting tool" will give u the ips and names and xuid.

Answer (score 0):

if your look to kick someone out of a game your hosting try this site

http://www.adivinedude.com

it has a tool with all the instructions and source code needed

Answer (score 0):

Use a tcpdump/wireshark (used to be ethereal) type of a tool to analyze the traffic. The problem then is that you will have to pinpoint which udp stream belongs to the nasty person.
If you are hosting the game and are able to kick people out, you might want to record traffic and then kick him out and see which stream stops. Another option is to send him private messages and try to see where they are sent.